# How to group on list of name with first letter?

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public string PeopleName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

List<ContactModel> contacts =new List<ContactModel>();

Contacts.Add(new ContactModel{PeopleName="Vijay Singh",PhoneNumber="9878987869"});
Contacts.Add(new ContactModel{PeopleName="Anuradha Patel",PhoneNumber="9878987869"});
Contacts.Add(new ContactModel{PeopleName="Binay Dixit",PhoneNumber="9878987869"});
```

I want to get a `List<char>` on Contact name First Letter like my list data => `V,A,B`

How to get this by LINQ in C#?

Comment: var results = Contacts.GroupBy(x => x.PeopleName[0]).ToList();

Comment: suppose the list return a,b,a,n,m so how to distinct this with this same linq statement?

Comment: The query returns a two dimensions array : results[key][ContactModel[]]

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do as follows:

```
var charList = contacts.Select(c => c.PeopleName.First()).ToList();
```

If you need `Distinct` first character list then do as follows:

```
var charList = contacts.Select(c => c.PeopleName.First()).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: suppose the list return a,b,a,n,m so how to distinct this with this same linq statement?

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ's `group ... by` operator (or `GroupBy()` method), which manipulates a collection, and `ToDictionary()`, which converts an `IEnumerable<T>` to `Dictionaty<T1, T2>`, and `ToList()` method, which takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and returns a `List:

LINQ operators:

```
Dictionary<char, List<ContactModel>> = (from contact in Contacts
                                   group contact by contact.PeopleName[0])
                                   ).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

LINQ methods:

```
Dictionary<char, List<ContactModel>> lst = Contacts.GroupBy(c => c.PeopleName[0])
                                       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: how to find the list item with matching first Char in linq?

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear whether you need Grouping or you just need the list of first characters.

Group By
If you are looking at grouping based on First Characters, you could do the following.

```
var result = contacts.GroupBy(x=>x.PeopleName.First());
```

Your output would be as follows.

[image]

If you want to do the same case-insensitively, you could

```
var result = contacts.GroupBy(x=>x.PeopleName.First().ToString(),StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

If you are looking for a List of first characters alone, you can do the following.

```
var result = contacts.GroupBy(x=>x.PeopleName.First()).Select(x=>x.Key);
```

Since you are grouping by First Letter, the duplicate keys wouldn't exist either eliminating the need to distinct as seen in some of your comments. 
Output for sample ,

[image]